# Can AviSynth handle MTS files?

Tags: codec, mpeg

I want to process MTS (MPEG Transport Stream) files from an AVCHD camcorder in AviSynth. Displaying with `AviSource()` says that the file couldn't be opened, displaying with `DirectShowSource()` says that the format is not supported.

I found no information about MTS on the AviSynth wiki. The [list of source filters](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/TWriteAVI#Source_Filters) has nothing on MTS or TS. I found [a thread about MTS and VirtualDub](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=130359) but I would prefer dealing only with the source file instead of converting to another format.

Can AviSynth handle MTS files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cross-platform wrapper library [FFmpegSource](https://github.com/FFMS/ffms2) (around FFmpeg) — particularly, its filter `FFmpegSource2()` (instead of built-in `AviSource()` or `DirectShowSource()`).

See [AviSynth Wiki](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/FFmpegSource) about it.

Comment: I think I was able to use the plugin (with `LoadPlugin("/path/to/ffms2/x86/ffms2.dll")`), and Media Player says `Windows Media Player is unable to open the file. It's possible that Media Player
does not support this type of file or that you need a codec that is not
installed. [Close] [Help online]`. A file `00009.MTS.ffindex` appeared next to the source. With the x64 path, I get an error from AviSynth, `error 0xc1`. Shall I update my question or is it a separate question?

Comment: Why not give a separate question? It's better than have 2 question in one.

Comment: See this follow-up thread: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29137/errors-in-ffmpegsource2-plugin-source-filter-for-avisynth for installation and usage of FFmpegSource2 for MTS and MP4 files.